# Phonegap add plugin for android not for ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have app for Phonegap/Cordova, in which I have set up two platform ios, android.  The main thing is that I want to add plugin which is support for both ios and android but I want to add for android perspective not for ios so that function call to android purpose not for ios, so how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible, plugins are installed for all supported platforms. You can use device plugin to check if it's android or iOS and call the plugin or not

Comment: what if i replace code of android in plugin and platform file ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can fork the plugin, remove all the folders of the platforms you don't want to use and then use your fork.

Comment: i think it would be best to handle platform seperation from your code. On application startup you can keep a platform variable and act accordingly when ever you need specific code to run for each platform